# google excel two way conversion

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, currency-formatting, two-way

I have simple yet specific thing i would like to do in Google spreadsheets. Basically it's currency conversion, but instead of usual solution (one way conversion) I need something more complex - both way conversion.

What i have is two cells:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1eLK.png

What I need is that conversion works in both ways.

- When I enter dollars (B2), eur (A2) are converted & shown
  automatically (by my own
  defined conversation rate)
- When I enter eur (A2), dollars (B2) are converted & shown
  automatically (by my own defined conversion rate)

It works similar like this converter https://www.google.lv/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=S3GpVJXKLYHmywOzsIHgDQ#q=dollar+to+eur only. I don't need to choose between multiple currencies, only $ and €.

Is there any script that I can use or am I missing some very easy solution here? Is it even possible to do in Google excel? Thank you guys!

Comment: Sorry I mean google sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klavs,

You CAN NOT do that. When you have a formula, suppose in "B1", based on a cell, suppose "A1", it adds a watch on change event of cell "A1".

This is how it is automatically calculated when you change the value in cell A1.

Now, if you again enter a formula in cell "A1" itself having a reference of cell "B1" which is already having a reference of cell "A1" in its formula - it will create a CIRCULAR REFERENCE problem and hence will throw an error.

you need different cells to produce different output and not referencing each other.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i think it's possible with some kind of script then. thank you! at least i wont spend more time on searching any easy way to do this.

Comment: cool, please mark that as answer if it answers your question!